NullInjectorError: No provider for Kn
When accessing an Angular application page for the first time, the screen goes blank and shows this error :
Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(e)[e -> e -> Kn]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Kn!
NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for Kn!
but if you exit and return to it the content appears. as I have been working with Angular for a short time I am having difficulty identifying the cause
The only possible answer I found would be that Kn had not been imported and that it would be necessary to update the Angular version, but I didn't find anything related to Kn and even after updating Angular from version 16 to 17 the error continues
I also didn't find anything related to Kn in the application or how to add

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible github repo

you need to identify what is 'Kn' in your code. it should be a provider or serveice that angular cannot find

@NarenMurali if possible github repo This isn't a good idea to promote the use of external websites, answer should be as self-contained as possible.

Kn is probably a minified / renamed variable. Try to get the error in uncompiled / uncompressed mode.
R3InjectorError usually happens when you are trying to automatically inject (i.e., in a component constructor arguments) something that is not provided at root app level. For example, a service without providedIn: 'root'.
